# Probability distribution values plot

Tags: r, plot, probability, histogram

I have

probability values: `0.06,0.06,0.1,0.08,0.12,0.16,0.14,0.14,0.08,0.02,0.04` ,summing up to 1

the corresponding intervals where a stochastic variable may take its value with the corresponding probability from the above list:

```
126,162,233,304,375,446,517,588,659,730,801,839
```

How can I plot the probability distribution?

On the x axis, the interval values, between the intervals histogram with the probability value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
x <- c(126,162,233,304,375,446,517,588,659,730,801,839)
p <- c(0.06,0.06,0.1,0.08,0.12,0.16,0.14,0.14,0.08,0.02,0.04)
plot(x,c(p,0),type="s")
lines(x,c(0,p),type="S")
rect(x[-1],0,x[-length(x)],p,col="lightblue")
```

for a quick answer? (With the `rect` included you might not need the `lines` call and might be able to change it to `plot(x,p,type="n")`.  As usual I would recommend `par(bty="l",lty=1)` for my preferred graphical defaults ...)

(Explanation: "s" and "S" are two different stair-step types (see Details in `?plot`): I used them both to get both the left and right boundaries of the distribution.)

**edit**: In your comments you say "(it) doesn't look like a histogram".  It's not quite clear what you want. I added rectangles in the example above -- maybe that does it?  Or you could do

```
b <- barplot(p,width=diff(x),space=0)
```

but getting the x-axis labels right is a pain.

Comment: x = c(126,162,233,304,375,446,517,588,659,730,801,839), p = c(0.06,0.06,0.1,0.08,0.12,0.16,0.14,0.14,0.08,0.02,0.04)
 plot(x,c(p,0),type="s")
lines(x,c(0,p),type="S")
show the graph but does not look like histogram. can you try it and see what I mean. Thanks

Comment: ok. say I give up on the right x axis labels. I just want to have the probability distribution in a raw way. (It should look like the histogram) how can we achieve it? Thanks for your answer

Comment: did you look at the code in the first part of my revised answer (with `rect`)? it looks a lot like the standard results of hist() to me (you could obviously set the x- and y-labels if you wanted).  If it doesn't look like a histogram to you, could you be more specific about what's wrong?

Comment: Add the argument `xlim = range(x) - x[1]` to the `barplot` command and then this will give the X axis labels: `axis(1, x - x[1], x)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: It wasn't clear to me whether he wanted the axis labels at the breakpoints (as I think your solution would do?) or evenly spaced ... but useful nonetheless.

Comment: @BB, For evenly spaced use the same xlim argument as in my prior comment but use this to draw the X axis: axis(1, pretty(x) - x[1], pretty(x))